# Nginx rewrite with and without trailing slash

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to create a set of rules that match a url with and without a trailing slash

Most of the answers were pointing me to use something similar to this.

```
location /node/file/ {                                                                                         
    rewrite ^/node/file/(.*)/(.*)$ /php/node-file.php?file=$1&name=$2;                                    
    rewrite ^/node/file/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /php/node-file.php?file=$1&name=$2;                                   │
}
```

But this does not match the trailing slash url.

How can I write a rule that matches urls that look like

```
http://example.com/node/file/abcd/1234/
http://example.com/node/file/abcd/1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `rewrite` statement includes `(.*)` as the last capture, which will match any string, including one with a trailing slash.

Use the character class `[^/]` to match any character except the `/`:

```
rewrite ^/node/file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /php/node-file.php?file=$1&name=$2;                                    
rewrite ^/node/file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /php/node-file.php?file=$1&name=$2;
```

Now you will notice that the first `rewrite` statement is unnecessary, as the second `rewrite` statement matches URIs both with and without a trailing `/`.

So all you need is:

```
rewrite ^/node/file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /php/node-file.php?file=$1&name=$2;
```

Comment: This works. It slipped my mind that .* will match everything, including the slash character